# detecting Label and based upon on condition make css change

Tags: jquery, css

Working on code where form fields are coming inside a label field..

I want to match certain form labels in jquery and if that is true it should make them uppercase. This is my try

```
$('#mypage form fieldset label').each(function () {
                if($(this).is(':contains("Case")')) {
                    $(this).css('text-transform','uppercase');
                }
            });
```

But it does not work, neither it shows me an alert, i am doing something wrong ad even not showing any error in console.

Comment: Could you show us your HMTL so we can see if you are selecting elements properly?

Comment: Your code looks like it should work. Yeah, we really need to see the HTML. Also, if you could put that in a jsFiddle we can test it.

Comment: You can also put the :contains in with the first selector rather than doing an extra loop

Comment: here is the fidle http://jsfiddle.net/9r8ge89y/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"STATE" and "state" are two different string. Therefore your code was not working. Change "state" to "STATE".

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#mypage form fieldset label').each(function () {
                if($(this).is(':contains("STATE")')) {
                    $(this).css('text-transform','uppercase');
                }
            }); 
});

<div class="group_r form_print memtop">
   <label>STATE</label>

<style>
   .form_print {
      COLOR: #666;
      FONT-SIZE: 11px;
      FONT-WEIGHT: bolder;
      text-shadow:0 1px 1px #b3b3b3;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform:lowercase !important;
    }
</style>
```

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9r8ge89y/4/)

Comment: can u remove my code, its urgent and update in jsfiddle and ink the link here, please please

Comment: but can u remove from post, that will be nice of you please

Comment: @user2784480: *why*? If he does then this answer becomes less useful to others in future. Why is it so important that it not be here?

Comment: @DavidThomas I have edited the answer again so that all the important information remain so that it will be useful. I have just removed the unwanted part only. Is it fine?